# The docker container does not run in detached mode

Tags: docker

When I run my docker container in detached mode by using the following command

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name tmp-cntr --net="host" -v /home/project:/root/ IMAGE-NAME
```

it does not appear when I list the containers by

```
docker ps
```

When I list all the containers by

```
docker ps -a
```

I can see that the container has exited. However, if I try to run the container with the same name it gives following error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/tmp-cntr" is already in use by container "4b7cf4084685ad7fcaeef3ca6a07ca594752c42cbfd6eb07850d7fe8f5289bc3". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

Is the container running or has it exited? What is the problem in my command? Please be kind enough to point out my mistake and explain how this can be corrected.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: try removing --name

Comment: As pointed out by @SiHa, there is no benefit in doing that as the exited containers will keep piling up.

Comment: How did you create the image? Via a Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, I created the image from the Dockerfile. Additionally, I want to mention one more thing. Now, when I am running the container with `-idt` flag, it is working as expected. However, it is still not working with `-d` flag only.

Answer (score 1):

It means the container created but exited, There maybe something wrong with your entrypoint that the container can't start successfully.

please have a check with `docker logs <container-id>` to show what's wrong.

Comment: I tried this, but the outcome seems very strange as `docker logs` return nothing. On the other hand, if I run the same thing in interactive mode, I am able to see logs. Should I focus on entrypoint then?

Answer (score -1):

Since you can't re-run, it means it's in `Exited` status.

You should run `docker logs tmp-cntr` to see what's wrong with the current exited container and then `docker rm tmp-cntr` to remove it.

Also you can remove `--name tmp-cntr` from your `docker run` command to prevent the same name issues instead of removing it every time, so debug it better.

Comment: removing `--name` just means that the exited containers will build up.

Comment: @SiHa that's for testing purposes to remove `--name` and see the logs, then re-run it again. If there's been no errors and it's up, then he can the final one. I used **Also** term to show the alternative way, not the first way.

Comment: @SiHa so how to see why it's stopped since you use `--rm` when the container stops with exited status and then removes?

Comment: I think @SiHa only answered just a part of the question, i.e., the reason of the conflict `docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/tmp-cntr" is already in use by container "`.

Comment: @fam yes, but finally did you solve your problem?

Comment: When I am running the container with `-idt` flag, it is working as expected. However, it is still not working with `-d` flag only.